# SIMD C# - Test shows no difference in speed. Why?

Tags: c#, simd, ryujit

For reference, see: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/SIMD-Sample-f2c8c35a

This is not a real-world test. I've installed Ryu-JIT, and ran the following code after running "enable-JIT.cmd" and after running "disable-JIT.cmd". I've turned off "Suppress JIT optimization on module load".

None of those show any difference in the speed of the loops, or whether they will run. Currently, they both hit 1.1~ seconds.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Numerics;


namespace SimdTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyVector3 am = new MyVector3(1, 2, 4);
            MyVector3 bm = new MyVector3(4, 2, 1);

            Vector3f at = new Vector3f(1, 2, 4);
            Vector3f bt = new Vector3f(4, 2, 1);


            int count = 200000000;


            TestMine(ref am, ref bm, count);
            TestTheirs(ref at, ref bt, count);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

        private static void TestMine(ref MyVector3 am, ref MyVector3 bm, int count)
        {
            var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
                am += bm;
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
        }

        private static void TestTheirs(ref Vector3f at, ref Vector3f bt, int count)
        {
            var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
                at += bt;
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
        }
    }


    struct MyVector3
    {
        public float x { get { return _x; } }
        public float y { get { return _y; } }
        public float z { get { return _z; } }


        private float _x;
        private float _y;
        private float _z;


        public MyVector3(float x, float y, float z)
        {
            this._x = x;
            this._y = y;
            this._z = z;
        }


        public static MyVector3 operator +(MyVector3 lhs, MyVector3 rhs)
        {
            return new MyVector3(lhs._x + rhs._x, lhs._y + rhs._y, lhs._z + rhs._z);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Further tests show a possible answer: With RyuJIT installed, both of them may be compiling to SIMD. Testing x86, I got 1.1~ sec for both. Testing x64, I got 0.56~ sec for both. I removed the Microsoft.Bcl.Simd package. There was no change in the x86 test of MyVector3 (I could not test Vector3f, as it is from .Bcl.Simd), and the x64 test slowed down to 4~ sec. What that seems to mean is that x86 already uses SIMD for at least obvious cases like MyVector3 operator+, while RyuJIT adds a more complete SIMD package to x64.

Comment: That's quite unlikely, one of the most important things that Vector3f does is provide memory alignment guarantees.  SIMD is *very* inflexible about that and very incompatible with CLR alignment.  Remove *ref* from the arguments and try again.  Only test x64 Release build and ensure the jitter optimizer is not disabled.

Comment: Maybe using SIMD with vector *pointers* is not supported? ref maps to a pointer. Look at the disassembly. Or maybe all the stores to memory are what's bounding the performance of this test. I don't know whether the JIT can optimize them out or not.

Comment: I removed the refs. No change. I also tested the actual .exe, not just in VSE. Same. Are you sure the latest RyuJIT con't automatically align SIMD candidates?

Comment: Ah! Solved, I think. The major slowdown is the for-loop. When I optimize the for-loop to do 10 operations (and 10x less loops), the SIMD Vector3f is faster.

Comment: That's not a solution in that it does not provide any insight into what was going on. Look at the disassembly.

Comment: As far as I know, examining the disassembly requires the full version of Visual Studio. Your point is valid, though. ...And it seems that either the price of VS has gone down to something reasonable, or I somehow never managed to find a purchase of VS not linked to MSDN.

Comment: Maybe the new JIT is just as bad as the old one. So far I have seen only disappointing results to the point where I wonder why they even rewrote it. Maybe they did it for the startup time which is mostly useful for desktop apps.

Comment: RyuJIT includes SIMD. I imagine that's a not inconsiderable reason. However, testing moving the code out of the method, or moving the parameters into the method, showed that RyuJIT is not nearly ready for primetime yet. Or even all that stable. Still, the potential is there.

Comment: You did not follow the instructions... "Tricky thing necessary until RyuJIT is final: Add a reference to Microsoft.Numerics.Vectors.Vector<T> to a class constructor that will be invoked BEFORE your methods that use the new Vector types. I’d suggest just putting it in your program’s entry class’s constructor. It must occur in the class constructor, not the instance constructor." http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clrcodegeneration/archive/2014/04/03/ryujit-ctp3-how-to-use-simd.aspx

Comment: Actually, I just added that, and I can confirm that building, running, then building, and running again in VSE has the same effect as adding that reference (both after enabling RyuJIT). Anyway, I have much better test data now that I've got a handle on what I'm looking at, and how to do so, and I can say that I was...Completely wrong. It's much faster. I'll post with actual numbers in an answer later, as well as a bit of advice for testing RyuJIT.

Comment: I am unsure if I can legally post the results I have, so have a pastebin of test code:

http://pastebin.com/WiX01PbT

Comment: Narf, are you able to add any additional datapoints at this stage? I'm keen to hear how the SIMD perf is (but not quite keen enough at this stage to fight with the CTP myself).

Comment: VectorMath.IsHardwareAccelerated should indicate if SIMD instructions are being used.